# multimedia files doesn't load with <base> tag html

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- <base href="https://www.google.com"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <img src = "/multimedia/FluencyGeek.PNG" >
    <video src="/multimedia/Chand Wala Mukhda.mp4" controls autoplay></video>
    <p>the <code style="background-color: #f1f1f1; color: green; padding: 2px; font-size: 105%; 
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"  >button</code> tag is best option</p>
</body>
</html>
```

my code works but if uncomment

```
 <base href="https://www.google.com">
```

then my image and video don't load. why?

Answer (score 2):

The base tag specifies the initial address for the image source. Google.com/multimedia doesn't provide an accurate address for the image or the video.
As the example down below says the address in the base tag has to be precise:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://www.w3schools.com/" target="_blank">
</head>
<body>

<h1>The base element</h1>

<p><img src="images/stickman.gif" width="24" height="39" alt="Stickman"> - Notice that we have only specified a relative address for the image. Since we have specified a base URL in the head section, the browser will look for the image at "https://www.w3schools.com/images/stickman.gif".</p>

<p><a href="tags/tag_base.asp">HTML base tag</a> - Notice that the link opens in a new window, even if it has no target="_blank" attribute. This is because the target attribute of the base element is set to "_blank".</p>

</body>
</html>
```